# Giving a WPF ItemsControl a different look based off whether ItemsSource holds a single value or multiple values?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

Are there any slick ways to style/template a WPF ItemsControl differently based off whether ItemsSource holds a single value or multiple values?

What I've done so far is to create a custom ItemsControl class which among other things displays the list of bound items as a horizontally oriented comma separated list. So far I'm pretty happy with the results however I want to show a more brief view of the bound data in cases where multiple values are bound and if only a single value is bound then I want to show a more extended view of the bound data with a longer string description. I figure this is probably best solved by dynamically choosing the template either based off a trigger or possibly by using a template selector but it's not yet clear to me how this would be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a DataTrigger in your style to replace the template:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Items.Count}" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <!-- Insert Template here -->
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

You could also add one for where the Value is 0 if you wanted to display a "no records" template.

Comment: I was just attempting to implement it this way. 

So I guess the idea would be to have the default template define the default multi-value behavior but then to handle a Count = 1 as a special case by using a trigger as you demonstrated. Does this sound right?

Comment: Yep, that sounds right. It should also automatically switch between them when the count changes.

Comment: Thanks, this technique works great for the situation I described above. Unfortunately I realized my case is a bit different in that I'm actually only interested in the number of items that are marked as IsSelected in my ItemsSource as opposed to the raw Count. Unfortunately I don't see an easy way to apply the same concept but I think your solution adequately addresses the question I originally posed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a StyleSelector.
[Here is a sampl](http://wangmo.wordpress.com/2007/09/15/styleselector-works-for-blind-style-listbox/)e.